# Как разбить строку по регулярному выражению в Python

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, pandas

Доброго дня! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как составить регулярное выражение и разбить строку такого типа:

Иванов Иван Иванович 12.02.1942 675195, Москва, ул. Ивановых, дом 15, 4512 125345 выдан Орденом Ивановых 11.11.2011.

Соответственно, разбить нужно так чтобы получить колонки:
ФИО, Дата, Адрес, Паспорт

Я пробовал так:

```
pattern = "[А-Я]*[0-9]."
df1 = df1.Name.str.split(pattern, expand=True)
```

но получается криво. Уверен есть вариант значительно лучше.

Comment: Попробуйте [`rx=r'(?P<Name>.*?)\s+(?P<Date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\s+(?P<Address>\d+,\s*.*?)\s+(?P<Passport>\d{4}\s\d{6}.*)'`](https://regex101.com/r/eU5S6g/1)  =>  `df1.Name.str.extract(rx, expand=True)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, спасибо. Возвращает ошибку "bad character in group name 'Add\u200c\u200bress' at position 52". Как ее можно исправить?

Comment: А вы зря копируете из комментария. СО добавляет мусор.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, скопировал по ссылке regex100, но результат тот же и ошибка в той же линии. В любом случае, спасибо за ссылку на ресурс. Буду экспериментировать!

Comment: [Регекс работает](http://ideone.com/kih6PD). По крайней мере, уж точно в нем нет ошибок.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, спасибо! Буду проверять что не так.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, не подскажете, почему regex разбивает правильно, а Python некоторые из этих строк записывает как Nan? Глюк?

Comment: У вас всегда все группы находят совпадение? Какие у вас входные данные?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, разобрался. Видимо где-то строки не полностью все-таки соответствовали. Я немного скорректировал шаблон и получил 100%. Правда, теперь другая проблема возникла. Насколько эффективно применять разбиение по регулярке, если у меня 3,5 млн. строк? Извините, что мучаю вопросами, тема новая для меня.

Comment: А какой у вас выбор, если данные у вас в таком неудобном виде? Будь они в формате CSV, было бы просто.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, согласен, но тормозит сильно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как текст неструктурирован, тут помогут только регулярные выражения. Пример:

```
rx = r'^(?P<Name>.*?)\s+(?P<Date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\s+(?P<Address>\d+,\s*.*?)\s+(?P<Passport>\d{4}\s\d{6}.*)$'
```

См. [демо на regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eU5S6g/1)

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?P<Name>.*?)` - любые 0+ символов (как можно меньше)
- `\s+` - 1+ пробелов
- `(?P<Date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})` - 2 цифры, точка, 2 цифры, точка, 4 цифры
- `\s+` - 1+ пробелов
- `(?P<Address>\d+,\s*.*?)` - 1+ цифр, `,`, 0+ пробелов, любые 0+ символов (как можно меньше)
- `\s+` 1+ пробелов
- `(?P<Passport>\d{4}\s\d{6}.*)` - 4 цифры, пробел, 6 цифр и 0+ любых символов (как можно больше, до конца строки)
- `$` - конец строки

Чтобы эта регулярка работала в pandas, нужно использовать её с [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df1 = df1.Name.str.extract(rx, expand=True)
```